# Trigonometry markup

Tags: trigonometry

Imagine we have the following problem;

$$\cos(x) = \cos(a) \Rightarrow x=a+k\times 2\pi\\ or \\x=-a+k\times 2\pi$$

And we have the following answers.. :

$$a=\frac{\pi}{3} \\or \\a=-\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Should I write:

$$a=-\frac{\pi}{3}$$

as:

$$a=\frac{5\pi}{3}$$

My book sometimes does this but I can't figure out why. Is this just a matter of preference? Or is there a rule for this?

(this question also applies to \sin(x) and other such forms.)

Regards, bowser.

Comment: It is just a matter of preference.  The author of your text is probably using angles in $[0, 2\pi)$ for $a$.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second angle whether for $ -\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $ \frac{5 \pi}{3}$ the tip of radius vector occupies the very same position. It is a just a matter of preference. For example if you stick to positive angles the latter can be taken. Or if want to take it easy, $ \pm  \frac{\pi}{3}$ is alright.